# Crear conexión a mysql con C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy realizando un proyecto de un sistema en c# pero este necesito que se conecte a una base de datos mysql con un inicio de sesión, no se muy bien como hacer e probado 3 diferentes códigos y no me resulta nada

```
cn.Open();
cmd.Connection = cn;
try
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from usuarios where usuario = '" + nombreUsuario.Text + "'and pass = '" + contraUsuario.Text + "'";
    int valor = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    //Comparamos si el valor recibido es 1 entonces existe si no NO
    if (valor == 1)
    {
        menu_principal mn = new menu_principal();
        mn.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else 
    { 
        mensajeError.Text = "No existe"; 
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    mensajeError.Text = "error siguiente" + ex;
}
cn.Close();
```

este es el codigo y cuando inicio el sistema y quiero iniciar sesion me da error en el cn.Open();
me dice que no se encontro Exception

Comment: Hola, pon el codigo que has probado y asi la gente podra comprobar en que te has equivocado y darte una ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: listo amigo ahi esta

Comment: tienes puesto correctamente el ConnectionString?, podrías probar a meter el `cn.Open();`dentro de un bloque `try{} catch{}` para ver con más detalle que excepción te está dando?

Comment: En el código que pones no aparece el ConnectionString que es probable que sea el responsable de tu problema. Además, deberias añadir a tu pregunta **la excepción exacta** que recibes con este código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que validar que el connection string que defines para conectarte a mysql sea correcto

[MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

que el servicio de mysql si esta remoto en otra pc este habilitado para conecciones remotas, ya que por defecto no lo esta.

Tienes que mostrar el mensaje del problema usando

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    mensajeError.Text = "error siguiente" + ex.Message;
}
```

solo la propiedad `Message` del Exception tiene la descripcion de lo que verdaderamente sucede.

Por ultimo tienes que usar parametros

```
string query = "select count(*) from usuarios where usuario = ?usuario and pass = ?pass";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?usuario", nombreUsuario.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pass", contraUsuario.Text);

int valor = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

no se concatene en el string los valores

Comment: sigue dandome error con el cn.Open();

Comment: Excepción no controlada del tipo 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' en MySql.Data.dll

Información adicional: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Uid = root; Password = YES; Database = usuarios; Port = 3306");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

Comment: eso tengo antes del public inicio_de_secion(){}, definiendo cn y cmd

Comment: es problema de la bd ya me dijo el error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usuario and pass?pass' at line 1

Comment: pero pudiste realziar la conexion a la db ? recuerda que debes poner el "=" en el where cuando comparas con el password, o sea `where usuario = ?usuario and pass = ?pass`

Comment: error siguienteFatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: error siguienteParameter '?usuario' has already been defined.

Comment: eso me sale e estado investigando

Comment: pero aun no le entiendo

Comment: si el error dice que a esta definido es porque estas suando en varios lugares la misma instancia del objeto command, debes hacer SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);  edito el codigo. No uses instancia de objetos globales